# Fazer um gráfico em android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Boa tarde pessoal.
Eu estou a iniciar programação em android e gostava se saber como é que eu posso construir um gráfico como este:
[image: Grafico]

Existe algum widget que posso arrastar ou tenho mesmo que escrever código?
P.s Eu uso o android studio

Comment: https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android

Comment: https://github.com/Androguide/HoloGraphLibrary

Answer (score 4):

Sim, você tem que escrever código, até porque você precisa fornecer os dados com os quais os gráficos serão construídos.

Porém, felizmente, existem ótimas bibliotecas prontas para isso, aqui vão algumas que eu recomendo:

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart

https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android